# При загрузке изображения оно изменяется, почему?

Tags: php, gd

Загрузил изображения этим кодом:

```
$w = 900;
$h = 900;

$img = imagecreate($w, $h);

$fill_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);

imagefill($img, 0, 0, $fill_color);

$image = imagecreatefrompng("img/test.png");
imagecopyresampled($img, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 900, 900, 900, 900);

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
```

Исходное изображение:
[image: Исходное изображение]

Получается это:
[image: Получившееся изображение]

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: `imagecreate()` попробуйте заменить на `imagecreatetruecolor()`. и какого размера у вас оригинальное изображение?

Comment: Размер: 900x900